# Buttons in terminal using python

Tags: python, button, terminal

Hi I was wondering if i could add buttons in my terminal using python as I am making a project and decided not to use tkinter and other GUI modules. Instead I wanted to do it in the python terminal and for your information I am using a MacBook.

I think that you can use the `cursers` module or something like so to make buttons just that I don't know how to do so :(

Thanks for any help provided! ;)

Comment: How can you add button to a interface which is text only

Comment: HI welcome to the community! Your question is overly broad for this site. Try looking into what packages would work for your application and give it a shot. If you have come across a specific issue, feel free to bring it up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Python we can not create a button in the terminal and there is no way at all and only using graphical environments this is done which is not in the terminal
You can do two things: a mouse and keyboard control with a click function, and if you do a Google search for this function, it will bring you
Or put a text yourself, for example print (1- hello)
And then define an input, such as go input
And then define an if and say if go == 1: print (hello)
There are two ways you can
I hope this article is useful for you and you have answered your question

Comment: Thank you. Even though I did not get the answer I expected, I got a good and reasonable one! Thanks for your patience